# Javascript return value run onclick after onclientclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wanted to run my onclick event after the onclientclick but the program keep pop up and ask Please select at least one to delete no matter my checkbox is clicked or not.

I think maybe my return value is wrong? Thanks for help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var gridView = document.getElementById("<%=grid1.ClientID %>");
            var checkBoxes = gridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete?")) {
                        alert("Ok");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    alert("Please select at least one to delete.");
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
       }

    </script>
```

Comment: before your `for(...){}` loop, if you put `console.log(checkBoxes);` what shows in the console?

Comment: your loop will just run once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the function after the confirm:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var gridView = document.getElementById("<%=grid1.ClientID %>");
        var checkBoxes = gridView.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure to delete?")) {
                    alert("Ok");
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
        alert("Please select at least one to delete.");
        return false;
   }

</script>
```